# How do I deploy my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC app with user secrets on my Windows hosting

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have been looking for this a few hours and can't seem to get a good result.

All my sensitive data is stored in my secrets, but how do I call it on the published server?